# Setting data type in ODataConventionModelBuilder

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I've seen in `OData` documentation that there are `Edm` types `Date` and `Time`. Currently in my database there are many `DATE` fields being represented in EF as DateTimes, so the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` is declaring them as `Edm.DateTime`. How can I change them to `Edm.Date`?

Was hoping I could do this:

```
entityType.Property(p => p.AgreementDate).EdmType = EdmType.Date;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding Edm type of certain property is mapped from the CLR type and can't be overrided by `ODataConventionModelBuilder`.

If you want to change the Edm type, you can ignore these properties within the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`.

After getting the Edm model by calling GetEdmModel on the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`, you can add these properties with Edm.Date to the Edm model by calling OData APIs.

Comment: That's very awkward. Wish MS would make this a possibility from the builder.

Comment: Changing the default Edm type would possibly affect the serialization and deserialization. You can create a work item for it in codeplex https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: I have tried your approach. The result is an exception: `An incompatible primitive type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=False]' was found for an item that was expected to be of type 'Edm.Date[Nullable=False]'.` Can you point me to an example where `Edm.Date` is used?

Comment: @veertien, you have to use `Microsoft.OData.Edm.Library.Date` for property type in your model (not just `DateTime`). For example: `class MyModel{  public Date AgreementDate {get;set;}}`

Comment: And, unfortunately, you cannot use `Microsoft.OData.Edm.Library.Date` with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer in case someone is interested in the details of how to implement Feng Zhao's suggestion. I didn't find the API too discoverable, so I wanted to share.

First, build your EDM model as usual with the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` but ignore the date property:

```
...
entitType.Ignore(p => p.AgreementDate);
...
IEdmModel model = builder.GetEdmModel();
```

Then add the date property "manually":

```
 var myType = (EdmStructuredType)model.FindDeclaredType(typeof(MyType).FullName);
 var dateType = (IEdmPrimitiveType)model.FindType("Edm.Date");
 myType.AddProperty(new EdmStructuralProperty(myType, "AgreementDate", new EdmPrimitiveTypeReference(dateType, false)));
```

That's it.

Comment: What OData version is this? I have OData v3, and when I `model.FindType("Edm.Date")`, a null value is returned.

Comment: This is OData v4. `Microsoft.OData.Edm`, Version 6.11.0 to be more specific.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will have to try when I move to OData 4.